# How to replace or change the default digit button

Tags: android, twitter-digits

I am trying to use my own text and preferred color on Twitter Digits for android app, as am building an app that uses mobile authentication.

here is my xml:

```
<com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsAuthButton
        android:id="@+id/auth_button"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dgts__digits_btn"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

and this is the button i tried using to overwrite the default button
but not working as expected, i just want a red button with the text "join" on it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:radius="8dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/tw__blue_default"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: Add links, posts, and code